# How to iterate over all matched groups?

Tags: python, regex

If you look at this [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%5BWIKI_LINK%3A.*%40(%3FP%3CWIKI_LINK%3E%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D%2B)&test_string=%5BWIKI_LINK%3A%20Welcome%20Link%40Welcome%5D%20field.%20Happy%20editing!%0A%5BWIKI_LINK%3A%20Hello%20Link%40Hello%5D%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) example, you can see that the expression would get me the actual text of a `WIKI_LINK`:

```
[WIKI_LINK: Whatever@Example]
```

However, I don't know how I get the result using Python's `re` package. `search()`, `match()`, `findall()` and `finditer()` do not give me a list of matches.

My goal is to replace all `[WIKI_LINK: ..]` expressions by the actual display text within a string.

```
Text [WIKI_LINK: Whatever@Example] text [WIKI_LINK: Whatever@Example]
```

would become just

```
Text Example text Example
```

Just for the sake of copy & pasteness:

```
import re

text = 'Text [WIKI_LINK: Example@Whatever] text [WIKI_LINK: Example@Whatever]'

p_wiki_link = re.compile(r'\[WIKI_LINK:.*@(?P<WIKI_LINK>[^\]]+)')

for f in re.finditer(p_wiki_link, text):
    print(f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `re.sub` with

```
\[WIKI_LINK:[^][]*@([^]]+)]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eLTlJa/1/)

**Details**

- `\[WIKI_LINK:` - a literal substring `[WIKI_LINK:`
- `[^][]*` - any 0+ chars othert than `[` and `]`
- `@` - a `@` char
- `([^]]+)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` backreference from the replacement pattern): any 1+ chars other than `]`
- `]` - a literal `]` char.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JTzTdA):

```
import re
text = 'Text [WIKI_LINK: Example@Whatever] text [WIKI_LINK: Example@Whatever]'
p_wiki_link = re.compile(r'\[WIKI_LINK:[^][]*@([^]]+)]')
print(p_wiki_link.sub(r'\1', text))
# => Text Whatever text Whatever
```

Comment: Wow. Awesome answer. Thanks for the additional explanation! More than just useful!

Comment: typo: result is `Text Example text Example` (oops, just noticed OP mixes the sample input around).. also, I'd have used `[^@]*@` instead of `[^][]*@`

Comment: @Sundeep Do not use `[^@]*@`, it may overmatch in case of a string like `Text [WIKI_LINK: Whatever] text [WIKI_LINK: Whatever@Example]`